# Read all files in a directory and output to a single file

Tags: python, regex, file-io

I have written a python script which searches a file using regular expressions. It finds a name and 2 numbers and writes them to an output file. I have a folder with many files, I would like to automate this process for every file in the folder and write to the same output file.

Here is my current attempt which works only for opening a single file.

```
import os
import re
directory = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
for files in directory:
    f = open("VALUE_WOOLWORTHS.txt", "r")
    searchlines = f.readlines()
    for line in searchlines:
        if '"Spread" keyvalue' in line:
            n = re.search(r'\keyvalue="(.*)', line)
            name = n.group()
            break
    f.close()
    count = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
        if '"VALUE (Base)">' in line:
            for line in searchlines[i:i+1]:
                m = re.search(r'\d+\.\d+', line)
                count = count + 1
                if count == 1: m1 = m.group()
                    if count == 2: 
                    m2 = m.group()
                    ff = open("test.txt","a")
                    output = '{} {} {}'.format(name, m1, m2)
                    print output
                    ff.write(output)

                if count == 2: 
                break
```

How can I edit the above to sequentially open all files in the current directory, do the search, write to the same output file, and then open the next file and repeat? I would like the output from each file to be displayed on a new line.

Many thanks

Comment: I am a bit confused by why you need to loop through searchlines twice. I think you can probably refactor into an more understandable form. Do you expect '"Spread" keyvalue' to be just before '"VALUE (Base)">'? You should provide an extract of the file you are scanning.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong and do not allow to understand what your are trying to achieve. Please fix it and considere to add an example of input and expected output.

Comment: @Spinor yes '"Spread" kevalue' occurs 2 lines above '"VALUE (Base)">'. Yes I know the code is messy but for some reason I could not get it to work otherwise, I think something weird was occurring to do with invisible spaces I had left. This was a temporary working code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "VALUE_WOOLWORTHS.txt" is one of the files you want to read from, simply change it to `files`:

```
for files in directory:
    f = open(files, "r")
```

And, for a newline in output file, change

```
output = '{} {} {}'.format(name, m1, m2)
```

to

```
output = '{} {} {}\n'.format(name, m1, m2)
```

, if you don't mind a trailing newline at the end.

Comment: Thanks very much! I want to copy paste the results in my output file into 3 corresponding columns in excel. Do you know how I can do this or do I need to change the output code in python?

Comment: @B. Dillon I think you can save it as a txt or csv file, then import it in excel. if your output values(`name`, `m1`, `m1`) don't contain space, current output should be okay.